# Global struct c++

Tags: c++, struct, linker, global

I'm aware that this question has been asked multiple times before, but I can't get this to work. For a special case I need to have a global struct that will be filled in one file, and read in another.

The following code gives me a linking error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_camera_data", referenced from:
      MyCameraData::return_sensor_shift() in extra-424af5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-5.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

common.h:

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H
struct MyCameraData
{
    float sensor_shift;
    float return_sensor_shift();
};
extern MyCameraData camera_data;
#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "common.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    MyCameraData camera_data;

    camera_data.sensor_shift = 5.0;

    std::cout << camera_data.return_sensor_shift() << std::endl;
}
```

extra.cpp:

```
#include "common.h"

float MyCameraData::return_sensor_shift(){
    return camera_data.sensor_shift;
}
```

There must be something I'm overlooking. Any ideas?

Comment: You declared `camera_data` as `extern`, which means "trust me, it's defined elsewhere". But you never defined it anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Cheers, that was it. Rookie error!

Comment: In the `main` function you define a *local* variable in the scope of the `main` function only. It is *not* the global variable you declared in the header file.

Comment: Furthermore, your `return_sensor_shift` member function makes no sense. It should not return the member variable from the global object, but from *this* object, simply by doing `return sensor_shift`. It seems you could use [a couple of good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read.

Comment: A getter `return_sensor_shift();` but the variable is public?

Answer (score 2):

You could move

```
MyCameraData camera_data;
```

from `main` to global scope in main.cpp to resolve the linker error. However, I suggest creating a file common.cpp and defining the variable in that file. That is cleaner than defining it in main.cpp.

common.cpp:

```
#include "common.h"
MyCameraData camera_data;
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "common.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    camera_data.sensor_shift = 5.0;
    std::cout << camera_data.return_sensor_shift() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This part is okay:

**Common.h**

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H
struct MyCameraData
{
    float sensor_shift;
    float return_sensor_shift();
};
extern MyCameraData camera_data;
#endif
```

Since you declared `camera_data` as `extern` in the header file which is only a declaration you are missing its definition.

To fix this add this file:

**Common.cpp**

```
#include "Common.h"
MyCameraData camera_data;
```

And that should fix your problem.